# Belongs_to different field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've inherited quite a weird table layout:

```
callbacks
id, note, user

admin
id, name, password
```

In callbacks, the user is set to the name of the admin rather than the actual ID. Now I need to be able to call `callbacks.user` and have rails lookup the admin with that name and then bind it to that record.

I have a model for `admin` that is called `users`

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default methods.

```
def user
  User.find_by_name(user_name)
end

def user=(obj)
  self.user_name = obj.name
end

def user_name
  self[:user]
end

def user_name=(name)
  self[:user] = name
end
```

Other option , to make it work with `belongs_to`, there is `primary_key` option but need to have a different name than the attribute `user`

```
 # Callback.rb
 belongs_to :user_model , :class => "User", :foreign_key => :user, :primary_key => :name

 # User.rb
 has_one :callback , :foreign_key => :user, :primary_key => :name
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to do that originally, but I wasn't sure this was a very "rails" way of going about it and wondered if you could use the `belongs_to` method

Comment: it is possible to make it work with `belongs_to` with primary key but you would need to override the default methods if you want to use `user` as the name for association

Comment: Interesting, thank you! It's such an awkward layout but this works so all good :)