# Passing a symbol as a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this scope in a model called `activity`:

`scope :today, where("DATE(qualify_date) = ?", Date.today)`

and I have another separate model (`user`) that will use that to calculate some figures and I want to be able to use:

`User.calls_for :today`

that will then call the`activity` model and the `today` scope but I can't figure out out to use the symbol provided to call that scope

The `calls_for` method will contain the following:

`activities.*scope*.to_a.sum(&:calls).to_i`

Comment: dont do that: `scope :today, where("DATE(qualify_date) = ?", Date.today)`, this will evaluate ONCE, setting "today" to the date you started your server. you'll need a block/lambda or even better, a class method, to implement such a scope

Comment: My bad, I will correct that now. @matt pointed that out :)

Comment: @demondeac11 has the best solution for what you are asking about. However why would you call `Activity` through the `User` class, why not call `Activity` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, `#send` is what you'll want to use. But you may want to consider using some meta programming...I'm guessing that besides the `:today` scope, you also have something like `:yesterday`, `:two_weeks_ago`, etc. scopes.

So, you can always do something like:

```
def calls_for(foo)
  activities.send(foo).sum(:calls).to_i
end


def method_missing(foo, *args, &block)
  if foomatch = foo.to_s.match(/^calls_for_(\w+)/)
    foo_scope = foomatch[1].to_s
    send(:calls_for, foo_scope)
  else
    super
  end
end

def respond_to?(meth, x=false)
  if meth.match(/^calls_for_(\w+)/)
    true
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You are going to want to use the send method, I also believe your call to #to_a is unnecessary since activities should return an ActiveRelation which is enumerable.

```
def calls_for scope = :today
  activities.send(scope).sum(&:calls).to_i
end
```

In the above method you can just call User.calls_for which will be the same as User.calls_for(:today). This will be pretty flexible for the future as you can now define multiple scopes and use the same method. i.e. calls_for(:yesterday)

Also define your scope as Matt has shown above so you don't run into the classic gotcha.

Comment: I think `sum(:calls)` (without the `&`) will do the sum calculation in SQL, which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do activities belong to a user? If so you can just call it directly:

```
@user.activities.today
```

Keep in mind that your scope needs to be a lambda so that it reevaluates each request, or it will cache the date at which it was first called.

```
# Ruby 1.8
scope :today, lambda { where("DATE(qualify_date) = ?", Date.today) }

# Ruby 1.9+
scope :today, -> { where("DATE(qualify_date) = ?", Date.today) }
```

Comment: They do, but due to a weird database layout I have inherited I have to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976498/belongs-to-different-field-name

Comment: Also, with that lambda you posted I get an error: `SyntaxError: /local/www/rails/admin/app/models/lead.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or │                                                                                                                      
tLAMBEG`

Comment: @andy Sorry that was a Rails 4 implementation, changed it to Rails 3.

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Rails 4 at the moment (`rails -v #=> Rails 4.0.0`)

Comment: In regards to the actual question: I can call it directly, but I'm looking to have about 4-5 scopes and `@user.calls_for(:today)` looks a lot better than `@user.activities.today.to_a.sum(&:calls)`

Comment: @andy I think I forgot to include that the where should be enclosed by {} - have edited.

Comment: @andy Your question has no mention of `calls` ... add some more detail.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Updated`

Comment: The `lambda` vs `->` syntax is not dependent to rails version but was introduce in ruby 1.9.x

Comment: FWIW note the syntax error was probably due to your ruby version not your rails version. -> is the [lambda shortcut](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/05/new-lambda-synt.html) introduced in 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit confused if you want to get activities for a special user or a list of all activities. If you want a to call it like this `User.call_for(:today)`:

```
def self.calls_for(date)
  Activity.call(date)
end
```

If you want `user.call_for(:today)`:

```
def calls_for(date)
  activities.call(date)
end
```

But is you see it would be easier just to write `Activity.today` or `user.activites.today`.

Comment: There's going to be a bunch of different scopes eventually. It's basically for summing up calls for that day for reporting

Comment: and it's for specific users. So I can do User.find_by_name('Bob').calls_for(:today) #=> 201

Comment: Yes than just use the second example and add it to our `user.rb`